# Apache: Multiple log files?

Tags: apache, logging

What are the `access.log.*` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache, I believe, does log rotation.  So these would be the older log files with the access.log file being the current one.

Comment: Apache doesn't actually do its own log rotation. Log rotation is usually handled by a package called (unsurprisingly) "logrotate" on *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

Apache / apache2 itself doesn't do its own log rotation. On *nix systems, logs (including logs by Apache) are usually rotated via [logrotate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation), a command which looks like a service but is actually only a script triggered by cron in defined intervals. (@nobody already pointed that out in comments). One default logrotate configuration appends ".1" to an older, rotated log, so a file like *access.log.1* would end up in your logs directory. This is what you are probably seeing.

**Is it possible to have apache log to multiple log files?**

The question's title can be ambiguous. For anyone coming here to learn if it is possible to make Apache write to multiple log files simultaneously, the answer is: Yes.

The *TransferLog* or *CustomLog* directives are used to define logfiles. These directives can be repeated to make Apache write to more than one log file. This also works for VHOSTS / Virtual Host entris. Only ancient Apache releases were limited to only one logfile per server configuration.